# JAXB Program to retrieve values from xml file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i'm trying to retrieve the values from xml using JAXB. Below in detail:

My OrderValidation.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <OrderValidation>
        <OrderType name="Activation-Activation">
            <Product>
                <Name>TV_SAT</Name>
                <ActionCode>ADD</ActionCode>
            </Product>
        </OrderType>
        <OrderType name="Change Owner-Change Owner">
            <Product>
                <Name>TV_SAT_EQUIPMENT</Name>
                <ActionCode>EXISTING</ActionCode>
            </Product>
        </OrderType>
    </OrderValidation>
```

Here is my Orderxml.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="OrderValidation")
public class Orderxml 
{
    private String name;
    private String Product;
    private String OrderType;

    public Orderxml() {}
    public Orderxml(String name, String productclass, String ordertype) 
    {
        super();

        this.name = name;
        this.Product = productclass;
        this.OrderType = ordertype;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getProductName()
    {
        return Product;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productclass)
    {
        this.Product = productclass;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getOrderType()
    {
        return OrderType;
    }
    public void setOrderType(String ordertype)
    {
        this.OrderType = ordertype;
    }
}
```

My UnMarshall code(Main class)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     try
     {
        File file = new File("C:///OrderValidation.xml");
        System.out.println(1);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Orderxml.class);
        System.out.println(2);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        System.out.println(3);
        Orderxml ord= (Orderxml) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(4);
        System.out.println(ord.getOrderType()+". "+ord.getProductName());
     }
     catch (JAXBException e)
     {
       System.out.println("Issue is here");
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

When i execute the code it is throwing the null as output. Please suggest me the changes in the code so as to retrieve the values. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide the exception stacktrace.

Comment: No exceptions are coming. output is coming as null.

Here is my output
1
2
3
4
null. null

Comment: Your class definition `Orderxml` doesn't match the XML that you provided... That's why you have `null`

Comment: can you please provide suggestion for the proper definition

Answer (score 2):

You JAXB POJOs dont seem to be correct. Based on your XML structure it should be something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="OrderValidation")
public class Orderxml 
{
    @XmlElement("OrderType") 
    private List<OrderType> orderTypes;
}



public class OrderType{
    @XmlElement("Product")
    private Product product;
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    private String name;
}


public class Product {
  @XmlElement("Name")
  private String name;
  @XmlElement("ActionCode")
  private String actionCode;
}
```

You can generate approximate xsd from XML using online tools and then use schemagen utility to generate POJOs than hand-writing it.

Comment: `XmlRootElement` is not necessary on `OrderType` and `Product`

Comment: can you please let me know why you are using three classes?

Comment: Thats how JAXB generates the POJOs. Try generating POJOs using schemagen

Comment: The `@XmlRootElement` annotation is also not a requirement if you use the `unmarshal(Source source, Class<T> declaredType)` method. JAXB needs to know what type of object your XML input should produce, which it can either do by checking the root element's name and finding out if some class is annotated as representing that, or if you explicitly tell it what type to unmarshal to. That may be necessary if the root element's name might be unpredictable. @Mani Vempati: he's using separate classes because Product and OrderType aren't Strings, they're structured XML and should be represented so.